# BlueZ Mesh : Handle models

Tags: algorithm, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez, mesh-network

I would like to know the dbus and algorithm to handle generic ble mesh models communication using the BlueZ Mesh's dbus API.

I have made a simple c++ code which interact with the Ble Mesh dbus API. I'm actually able to make a proxy node which can provision unprovisioned nodes.

And now I don't now which dbus function to use to send a model message :

- `void Publish(object element_path, uint16 model, dict options, array{byte} data)`
- `void Send(object element_path, uint16 destination, uint16 key_index, dict options, array{byte} data)`

I think its the first but I don't now how to create/specifiate the model to use. Also how can I create and handle a model and its messages ?